# Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck while shutting down. systemd-shutdown[1] waiting for process tlp

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, systemd, tlp

My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is stuck while shutting down, saying:

```
 systemd-shutdown[1] : waiting for process : tlp
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Here is a screenshot of what I have]

Comment: TLP is a battery managment system installed if a battery is detected during install,can you please edit your pc spesification into your question.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I have the same problem on my HP OMEN 15, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Yes it fixed after i update the kernel